# how to display a button on a website using jquery in making firefox plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-plugins, firefox-addon

[image: the button position]
<sub>(source: [trillian.im](http://ft.trillian.im/bharris007/68aDvvaxg-oUhHoJ6DCV.png))</sub>

[image: after clicking on the button]
<sub>(source: [trillian.im](http://ft.trillian.im/bharris007/68aDzRxcg-M58h2nAPHh.png))</sub>

So when i press the button i should get a popup in the style as shown.i think i can do it by Jquery.secondly it should appear permanently on my gmail account once i have installed it.just like http://www.rightinbox.com/.thanks in advance

Comment: actually i want to make a firefox plugin and when i will intall it a button will appear permanently on my gmail account just like rightinbox.com button...when i will press that button it will show a popup "hello world" message as shown in pictrz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bulding HTML in a Firefox add-on is quite a challenge. You can't use innerHtml. For many alternatives check out these two articles on MDN:

- For a nice solution: [Appendix E: DOM Building and HTML Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion?action=edit)
- For a straight one: [How to create a DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_create_a_DOM_tree)

You should inspect what styles is gmail is using, and replicate that, just like I did on YouTube, so it will look really nice:

[image: youtube add-on image replication]

As for appending event to it, you can simply use [AddEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (if you really want to use jQuery). I can't provide full code here, because it would take up too much space, it's too much work and it's a work you will have to do, if you want to achieve anything.